# 3rd dynamic dropdownlist value compare with 4th table value from botton -> show div?

Tags: javascript, function, drop-down-menu

Honestly been looking everywhere..

The traditional 3-dropdown list dynamically populated from database:

> 1st table gives airport departure
>
> 2nd table gives airports choices
>   from 1st choice
>
> 3rd table show routes between 1 and 2.

That works perfectly!!

When passenger chooses a route from the 3rd drop list I want to check if the value from 3rd dropdownlist is represented in a 4th table called "donations"

Some routes are marked for donation possibility where passengers can donate their unused baggagecapacity to charity

My last hurdle is:

when 3rd list is selected --> check for donationpossibilities--> if possible then show a hidden `div` on `submit`

...

I've tried and read so much and gotten a lot more clever and I think I have the query to check the values in order, but I'm lost...

Comment: Why does this sound like homework?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what programming language you are using to load the dropdowns from your database, but one option that you could try is that when you are adding the html option elements to the 3rd dropdown list you could add a data attribute to each, for example:

```
 <option value="route 1" data-can-donate="true">...</option>
```

Then if you are using jquery you could bind the change event to the 3rd dropdown and do something like this:

```
 $('#ddlRoutes').change(function() {
      var canDonate = $('#ddlRoutes > option:selected').data('can-donate');
      if (canDonate) {
           $('#myDiv').show();
      }
 };
```

Obviously this is untested but it may work for what you are trying to do.